# setAudioSamplingRate not working for older device (Android 2.3.4)

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I need to record at a sampling rate of at least 44.1 kHz. I've tested the following code on my newer device (Android 4.1.2) and the recorded audio will have different sampling rates based on my input. However, when I use my older device (Android 2.3.4), regardless of what sampling rate I choose, it always returns a file sampled at 8 kHz.

Both the output format and audio encoder are API level 10, which is below the level of my older device. I can't fathom that my older device (Droid X) could have hardware that only supports an 8 kHz audio sampling rate, so I am assuming there must be another way to enforce the sampling rate I want.

```
private void startRecording() {

            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);


            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
            }

            mRecorder.start();
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the IOException isn't being thrown? (I.e., have you checked your logcat?)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. There is no IOException in my logcat, and my app runs fine - it does record to an mp4, but the recorded file is always 8 kHz. As an aside, I did find that my old phone can record at a higher rate than 8 kHz, but I don't know how to make it do so with my app. I know this because I generated a linear chirp that goes up to 6 kHz and there is no signal distortion when I record with my camera, while there is with my current setup.

Comment: Hmm. The only other thought I can offer right now is to verify that a new sound file is actually being generated each time -- i.e., that you're not looking at older results.

Comment: where r u checking sampling rate.install mediainfo and then check.

Comment: I'm uploading the completed file onto my PC, and I can view the sampling rate in both the properties of the file as well as MATLAB.

Comment: In my case, regardless used settings, it always records 16KHz for mono or 32KHz for stereo (like 8KHz per channel).

Answer (score 1):

Set the `OutputFormat` to:

```
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
```

Thenn try. It will work.